# file_get_contents() returns empty string, allow_url_fopen is enabled

Tags: php

file_get_contents() returns empty string even though all extensions and functions required seem to be enabled.

I have gone through all similar questions and tried their fixes with no success.
I'm not receiving any errors, I have tried with multiple URLs both remote and local.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {
echo "HTML: <br>";
$html=file_get_contents("https://www.google.co.uk");
var_dump($html);

echo "<hr><br>";

if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
echo "allow_url_fopen() exists";
}
else {
echo "allow_url_fopen() does not exist";
}


echo "<br>";
if (function_exists('file_get_contents')) {
echo "file_get_contents() exists";
}
else {
echo "file_get_contents() does not exist";
}



echo "<br>";
$w = stream_get_wrappers();
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "<br>";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "<br>";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "<br>";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_export($w);

echo "<br>";
if( ini_get('allow_url_include') ) {
echo "allow_url_include() exists";
}
else {
echo "<font style='color:red;'>allow_url_include() does not exist</font>";
}

echo "<br>";
if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) {
    echo "<font style='color:red;'>openssl does not exist</font>";
}
else {
    echo "openssl exists";
}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Page returns:

```
HTML: 
string(0) ""

allow_url_fopen() exists
file_get_contents() exists
openssl: yes
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: yes
wrappers: array ( 0 => 'compress.zlib', 1 => 'compress.bzip2', 2 => 'dict', 3 => 'ftp', 4 => 'ftps', 5 => 'gopher', 6 => 'http', 7 => 'https', 8 => 'imap', 9 => 'imaps', 10 => 'ldap', 11 => 'ldaps', 12 => 'pop3', 13 => 'pop3s', 14 => 'rtsp', 15 => 'smb', 16 => 'smbs', 17 => 'smtp', 18 => 'smtps', 19 => 'telnet', 20 => 'tftp', 21 => 'php', 22 => 'file', 23 => 'glob', 24 => 'data', 25 => 'phar', 26 => 'zip', )
allow_url_include() exists
openssl exists
```

I have also tried chmod 777 and 755.

I can't use cURL as file_get_contents() is apart of a framework I'll be using in the future.

Comment: "file_get_contents() is apart of a framework"...what do you really mean by this? It's a built-in PHP function. What framework is there which actively means you can't use cURL. Not sure I understand your point.

Comment: Do you `var_dump($html);` on a webpage or in your console? (Because at least for me on console there's output). Have you tried any other URL?

Comment: Maybe framework isn't the correct terminology, I am taking over a project and the source uses file_get_contents() in multiple places, and it's all intertwined to use the response of file_get_contents(), I don't have time to rewrite it using cURL, especially when it worked on an old server. I'm running this on a webpage.

Comment: Ok that does make a bit more sense. Is `allow_url_fopen` set correctly in your config? http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen . You appear to be checking for its existence, but not what is value is. It should always exist. The value is more important - it needs to be set to true. It's a boolean, not a function. And it's not clear what exactly you did with chmod? What file's value did you change? Since you're trying to call a URL, I can't see how file permissions would affect anything.

Comment: phpinfo() shows "allow_url_fopen On", I saw one answer on a similar question saying to chmod the php file to 777 or 755, so I was just putting it in there that I have tried it.

Comment: that would apply to a local file (not a URL) you were trying to open via file_get_contents, so you'd have permission to open it. The permissions on the PHP script you're actually executing are totally irrelevant, your code is not trying to open itself, and your webserver can clearly already open and execute it, otherwise you wouldn't have got to this point. 777 is not a good permissions status for a web-served PHP script, it allows too many people to modify it - potentially someone using your website could tamper with it, if they knew what to do. 755 is more appropriate.

Comment: I have tried fsockopen("https://www.google.co.uk", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30); and I get the error 'Unable to find the socket transport "https"', maybe this is why file_get_contents() is failing? But what do I need to fix this, looking it up I see enable openssl, but that's already enabled.

Comment: well, does it fail if you try to open a http-only website?

Comment: It gives me the same error, except http instead of https.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
  <?php
    $url = 'https://www.google.co.uk';
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($data);
    echo '</pre>';
    // Close handle

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but check the last line of my question and the comments.